# How to find order of permutation for this example?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

The question asks to compute the orders of the permutations. I think this is a non-disjoint cycle, so I'm not sure exactly how to find the order. Can someone please show me the steps on how to do this or an explanation? Do I just find the product? Thank you.
(2 1 4 6 3)(1 2)(3 4 5)

Comment: The order of a permutation $\sigma$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sigma^n = \mathrm{id}$ where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity permutation. In this case you can just compute $\sigma^2$, $\sigma^3$, etc. until you reach the identity permutation.

Comment: You could also try expressing the permutation as a product of disjoint cycles. The order of a product of disjoint cycles is the LCM of the orders of the cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as a product of disjoint cycles: $(21463)(12)(345)=(245)(36)$.  Thus the order is $6$, the lcm of the orders of the disjoint cycles.

Comment: How did you get (245)(36)? Sorry, can you show me? I'm getting confused...

Comment: What I do is to just take elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and apply the permutation, to see where they go.  You could start anywhere.  Take, say, $3$.  We get $3\to6\to3$.  So that's $(36)$.  The permutation literally just comes apart into disjoint cycles.  Now grab an element of $\{1,2,4,5\}$.  Say $5$  (but you can take any of them).  Now $5\to2\to4\to5$.  That's $(524)=(245)$.  Remember, apply the permutation from right to left.

Comment: Oh yeah, and note that $1\to1$.

Answer (score 0):

The original cycles are not written in disjoint cycles. You should convert it into the disjoint cycles. Once you get the disjoint cycles, the order is the least common multiple of each order of cycle.